# Passing object by reference constructed in function call

Tags: c++

we use some functions like this:

```
std::string const & GetValue(std::string const & val) {
return val;
}
```

Is there a way to break compilation if a user is passing a temporary, because
the code is sometimes misused using function calls like the following:

```
std::string const & abc = GetValue(std::string("Value"));
```

And is there a difference (regarding the lifetime of the passed object) if
the return value is not assigned to a reference, but to an object?

```
std::string def = GetValue(std::string("Value"));
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kerrek SB 's answer covers first part, when it comes to second part of your question the answer is, no there's no dangerous, you would be effectively copying the string that is passed even if it's a temporary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a deleted rvalue overload to prohibit binding to rvalues entirely:

```
void GetValue(std::string && val) = delete;
```

Alternatively, you could make the rvalue overload return a prvalue, thus avoiding dangling references:

```
std::string GetValue(std::string && val) { return GetValue(val); }
```